# Codeigniter: recommended way to pass user input to a controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to codeigniter, and just wanted to be sure I'm passing parameters in right way.

codeigniter can take regular GET/POST input parameters, that can be accessed in the controller using input class.

1. eg:
   $this->input->get/post('param1', TRUE);
2. Another way is to pass it as
   http://xyz.com/ci/index.php/cont/func/param1
   where param1 is available to a method in cont as 'func($param1){ }'

a.
In the 2nd case, does CI sanitizes user input automatically or is it upto me (I guess it is latter) ?
If I've to do it, then how to do it?

b.
Which is the recommended way to pass user input (1 vs 2) ?

c.
what are the pros/cons of 'Enabling/Disabling Query Strings' ?

d.
In CI, is there a way to sanitize/validate user input like Inspekt does ?

Comment: To learn how to sanitize read this page in the manual http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/security.html

Comment: @crypticツ thx for quick response, I think that answers q 'a' to some extent. what do you think about q 'b' ?

Comment: It depends on the context of the data. Are you expecting it to come from a form, an API request, a regular old navigation link, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ANSWERS**

**A**  In the 2nd case, does CI sanitizes user input automatically or is it upto me (I guess it is latter) ? If I've to do it, then how to do it?:

> **The Input Class**
>   The second optional parameter lets you run the data through the XSS
>   filter. It's enabled by setting the second parameter to boolean TRUE;

You may want to sanitize it *still* depending on how you would use it. But for me i still sanitize it on my own ways.On how i wanted it to be.

**B** Which is the recommended way to pass user input (1 vs 2) ?:

I do not think that there are limits on how or what choice of input you use, when data is comming from a `FORM input` then you will use `POST` since you cannot pass form input in `URL`,(or you could it just not recomended) style like example `2`, if it is coming from a `API` or some other sources definitely the best way to do it is via `GET` or CI's `$this->uri->segment()` function. or the `function(param1)` method

**C** what are the pros/cons of 'Enabling/Disabling Query Strings' ?:

well you can still use query string even if it is disabled, i have not seen any disadvantages or advantages of disabling or enabling it,

but your could simply pass `www.example.com/?param1=foo&param2=bar` on the URI and simply use `#this->input->get('param1')` to retrieve it, i use this much since i have to pass encrypted data on the `URI`.

**D** In CI, is there a way to sanitize/validate user input like Inspekt does ? :

If you want inspekt's functionalities, you can integrate inspekt to CI.

Comment: You didn't give a clear answer to A though: when passed as `http://example.com/ci/index.php/cont/func/param1`, is $param1 sanitized automatically?